# Spring Asynchronous calling support?

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring 2.5. i want to make asynchronous service calls. i know spring 3.x has support for making asynchronous calls using `@Async` annotation.
Is there any equivalent mechanism in 2.5 to make asynchronous calls?
If not is there any alternative way to make asynchronous service calls ?
 Please suggest me!

Thanks!

Comment: Spring 3.2.2 is currently available. Why are you still using this quite old version of the framework? You're likely facing more serious problems in the future too.

Comment: @Lion, Thanx for your reply. Is there any alternative?

Comment: I did no practical stuff in Spring 2.5 and I don't know whether it has something that can be used to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0):

With 2.5 my guess is you would be able to user `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and schedule a task using a cron expression. You could use the schedule method in this class. See the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html?is-external=true).

The code might look like this

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor sched = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10);
sched.schedule() -- API you need to call
```